# MongoDb Sharding setup over Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to setup the mongodb sharding cluster over the replica set.
I have setup the replica set over 3 machine, so for sharding cluster can i use these machine?
My replica set status is as below.

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "repSet",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-01-12T09:49:10Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.1.4.138:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 94839,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1357901076000, 4),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-01-11T10:44:36Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-01-12T09:49:10Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "errmsg" : "still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 50f04939:1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.1.4.21:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 94840,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1357982990000, 5587),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-01-12T09:29:50Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.1.4.88:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 3,
            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
            "uptime" : 87517,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1357900674000, 10),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-01-11T10:37:54Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-01-12T09:49:10Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "errmsg" : "still syncing, not yet to minValid optime 50f04939:1"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I gone through the mongodb sharding setup doc but didn't get how to setup.

Create the following data directories for three config database instances:

```
    /data/example/config1
    /data/example/config2
    /data/example/config3
```

Issue the following command at the system prompt:

```
mkdir -p /data/example/config1 /data/example/config2 /data/example/config3
```

In a separate terminal window or GNU Screen window, start the config databases by running the following commands:

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/example/config1 --port 20001
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/example/config2 --port 20002
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/example/config3 --port 20003
```

My current data directory is `/var/lib/mongodb`, so i don't want to create seperate directory.
So how can i use the current data directory and what steps to follow on all three servers.

Thanks
Raju

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial to convert a Replica Set to a Replicated Shard Cluster:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/